# How to set margin in react native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to set the margins on a box in react native, but the behavior is very strange. If I set marginLeft: 10, the margin is 10 on the left. But if I also set marginRight: 10, then the margin on the left is 20 and on the right is 20. Here is my code:

```
// ResultList.js
const box = {
  backgroundColor: 'green',
  marginLeft: 10,
  marginRight: 10
}
return (
  <View style={box}>
    <ResultItem />
    <ResultItem />
    <ResultItem />
    <ResultItem />
    <ResultItem />
  </View>
) 

// ResultItem.js
return (
  <View style={{margin: 0}}>
    <Text style={{margin: 0}}>
      This is text Here. This is more text testing. 
      This is text Here. This is more text testing
    </Text>
  </View>
)
```

This code produces the following image. Where I have drawn the black bars is where the green box should align to. It is worth noting that if I remove `marginRight: 10`, then the left margin behaves correctly. Only when I add in the marginRight is it wrong.

[image]

Code for Blue background view:

```
App.js
return (
  <View style={styles.container}> 
    <ResultList />
  </View>
);

container: {
  flex: 1,
  alignItems: 'center',
  backgroundColor: 'blue'
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code of Blue View?

Comment: ok just added it in @Jebin

Answer (score 4):

Try to use **marginHorizontal** instead of marginLeft and marginRight.

```
const box = {
  backgroundColor: 'green',
  marginHorizontal:10
}
```

Comment: this produces the same result as before

Comment: @joey sorry for inconvenience just remove that margin from there.

Answer (score 2):

Can you remove all margin and add paddingHorizontal to your container class like this

```
container: {
  flex: 1,
  alignItems: 'center',
  backgroundColor: 'blue',
  paddingHorizontal: 10
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as i see you defined margin once in `const box = { ... }`
so result item will be rendered in  a view that have `marginRight: 10 , marginLeft : 10` style,and if you set the margin in ResultItem.js component ,total margin is: box margin + ResultItem.js margin.
and if you dont set the `width` in `<Text>` component,width must be in range of 0 and text lenght,i suggest you to set the `width` in `<Text>` component so that will be easier to set margin and see the result